# Java не видит классы

Tags: java

Решил потренироваться на сборке Lineage. Сам сервер поднимается нормально, но не грузиться ни один квест. Я так понял из-за того, что *.java файлы не могут скомпилироваться, поскольку в них подключены классы, которые он не видит.

`La_Server\classes` - это пусть к классам.
`La_Server\gameserver\data\scripts\ai` - это путь к файлу, в котором импортируются классы.
Вообще все файлы *.java лежат по пути `La_Server\gameserver\data\scripts`
Прикрепляю скрин ошибки и скрин начала одного из файлов. Делаю все это на Windows 10 x64. JDK Установлено. Переменные среды прописаны.

Честно, даже не знаю больше какие данные Вам предоставить, чтобы помогли разобраться. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть [баг в Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=255931) приводящий к таким ошибкам.

Comment: Дело в том, что никаких IDE я не использовал. а взял готовую сборку. И вообще не пойму, какой файл запускает компиляцию((

Comment: Начните лучше с чего-нибудь попроще.

Comment: Ну я не то, чтобы собрался изучать java. просто мне всегда было интересно ковыряться в  подобного рода вещах. Но второй день уже пошел... нервы сдают

Comment: [Lineage 2 форум](https://forum.zone-game.info/forumdisplay.php?f=34) - там давным давно решили такие вопросы. Да и вообще, лыжа - это полный шлак. И кстати, вам ошибка говорит, что версия явы должна быть 1..6, а у вас скорее всего 8. Следует в компиляторе поправить.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, проблема была в том, что вы указали в переменную classpath не тот класс (те классы), которые нужны.

[The type ... cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547162/eclipse-error-indirectly-referenced-from-required-class-files)

И почитайте, как правильно указывать [classpath](http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html) - это тоже важно в реализации.